# How to troubleshoot MySQL procedure - Why loop is reaching max runs?

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, procedure, procedures

I have MySQL stored procedure that will create temporary table from remote server using FEDERATED tables. Then the procedure used these temporary table to do some work.

I am seeing some issue where I get an error like

```
Unable to connect to foreign data source
Got timeout reading communication packets
Unable to connect to foreign data source
Got error 1430 from storage engine
```

The problem here is that if these temporary table failed to create the entire procedure fails because the tables do not exists.

So I thought I can do some checking after the attempt to create temporary table and if the attempt return error then I go back and try it again. to stop an infinite loop I added a condition to quite after 10 tries.

The issue that i am running into is that the script quits and it does not run all the way to the end.

here is a portion of the procedure where the procedure is quitting and not sure why.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`10.%` PROCEDURE `act`()
MAIN: 
BEGIN

DECLARE current_procedure_name CHAR(60) DEFAULT 'activities';
DECLARE last_run_time DATETIME DEFAULT NULL;
DECLARE current_run_time_start DATETIME DEFAULT NOW();

    -- set the SQL mode to ''
    SET SQL_MODE = '';

    -- set MySQL Safe mode OFF on update
    SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;

SET @trys = 0;

loop_label:  LOOP

    SET  @trys :=  @trys+1;
    -- db.view_users is a federated table
    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS view_users1, view_users2, view_users3;
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE view_users1 (KEY(user_id)) ENGINE=MEMORY AS 
    SELECT user_id, fullname
    FROM db.view_users;

    IF(@@error_count > 0 OR @trys > 10) THEN

        -- if there are too many tries to create the temporary table and it keeps failing Quit!!
        IF( @trys > 10) THEN
             LEAVE MAIN;
        ELSE 
            -- sleep for 10 seconds and go back to create the table again
            SELECT SLEEP(10);
            ITERATE  loop_label;
        END IF;


    END IF;

    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE view_users2 (KEY(user_id)) ENGINE=MEMORY AS 
    SELECT * FROM view_users1;

    IF(@@error_count > 0) THEN
        ITERATE  loop_label;
    END IF;

    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE view_users3 (KEY(user_id)) ENGINE=MEMORY AS 
    SELECT * FROM view_users1;

    IF(@@error_count > 0) THEN
        ITERATE  loop_label;
    END IF;

END LOOP;


-- set MySQL Safe mode back ON on update
    SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 1;
END
```

How can I find out why it is quitting? it seem that `@trys` is reaching 11 and it quits but I don't understand why  would it?

I have tried to run this code outside the procedure and the second line returns 0 error;

```
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS view_users1, view_users2, view_users3;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE view_users1 (KEY(user_id)) ENGINE=MEMORY AS 
SELECT user_id, fullname
FROM db.view_users;
SELECT @@error_count;
```

A second question, is there a better approach for this problem? it is important that this procedure runs all the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figure out the cause of the issue.

from the manual [13.6.5.5 LOOP Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/loop.html)

> The statements within the loop are repeated until the loop is
>   terminated. Usually, this is accomplished with a LEAVE statement.
>   Within a stored function, RETURN can also be used, which exits the
>   function entirely

at the end just before `END LOOP;`  I needed to add `LEAVE loop_label` to end the LOOP other wise it will continue until @trys reaches 11;